# 500 un is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In my Nuxt 3, Typescript project, when i made build and deploy to server i catch this error, but i dont un constructor in my project
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whcDX.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxWEI.png)

i try remove images but nothing changes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa9Fj.png)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It's unknown what's the problem and how to fix it. It needs to be reproduced and currently this can be done only on your side. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The thing you can do is to use a debugger and debug what `un` is. From the context it looks like it is `URL` global and it was changed for some reason to be local variable. The next time you can do is to either enable sourcemaps to make code appear correctly or disable a minifier